# JQuery- Input Value Isn't Changing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I don't understand why the value isn't changing for this input from the website. I've tried this jquery code:

```
$('input[type=text].u').val('http://website/');
```

But it isn't changing or working:

https://jsfiddle.net/cq4e02yj/

Also I've tried to trigger click the button but that isn't working either.

-Thanks

Comment: Many of these jsfiddles you are linking to are not including jQuery.  You must include jQuery for any jQuery logic to work.  Please review your errors before stating the logic does not work.

Comment: @Taplar I never voted down a solution. I genuinely appreciate your time and help...

Comment: It's cool then.  Just always remember to hit F12 to crack open your developer tools to see if you have any errors.

Comment: @Taplar Thank you so much! I'm actualy using xcode and injecting this in a uiwebview. I forgot to include jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here's a first working solution.** You are missing the quotes around type="text". Hope it helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#myButton").click(function(){
 $('input[type="text"]').val('http://website/');

})
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center><input name="u" id="input" size="60" class="textbox" value="http:/s/" type="text"><input value="Change My IP Address" id = "myButton" class="button" type="submit"></center>
```

**Here's a second solution without clicking on button.**

```js
$('input[type="text"]').val('http://website/');
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center><input name="u" id="input" size="60" class="textbox" value="http:/s/" type="text"><input value="Change My IP Address" id = "myButton" class="button" type="submit"></center>
```

Comment: You also removed his '.u' check.

Comment: @Taplar and you added a class 'u' . It looks like he did NOT have the 'u' class but you added it

Comment: Even with that it still doesn't work. The html is from a website. I tried the code you gave me, it doesn't work. Here is the fiddle with the full website html: https://jsfiddle.net/cq4e02yj/5/

Comment: @MGames You're not loading jQuery

Comment: @MGames Hope my solutions were helpful to you. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @HenryDev Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

The input does not have a class of 'u'.  `.u` is a class selector.  If you put that on the class then your fiddle works.

If you want to keep the selector the same...

```js
$('input[type=text].u').val('http://website/');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center><input name="u" id="input" size="60" class="textbox u" value="http:/s/" type="text"><input value="Change My IP Address" class="button" type="submit"></center>
```

Comment: Provided you also fix your fiddle to include jQuery.

Comment: And if you do that your selector could be changed to just `$('.u')`

Comment: If I do     $('.textbox').val('http://website/');    or      $('input[name=\"u\"]').val("http://website/");  it still doesn't work

Comment: Sure, you can do that too.  Whatever change you want to do to make the selector valid.  Just as it is, it is not with the markup you have.

Comment: I've tried the snippets I commented before, it doesn't work in the fiddle.

Comment: Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cq4e02yj/3/, you forgot about including jquery as an external resource, and your selector was wrong

Comment: Even with that it still doesn't work. The html is from a website. I tried the code you gave me, it doesn't work. Here is the fiddle with the full website html: jsfiddle.net/cq4e02yj/5

Comment: That does indeed work.  You are not including jQuery in that fiddle.  Do so and it will work. http://jsfiddle.net/cq4e02yj/6/  Further more, that code snipplet up above, not on jsfiddle, also work.